# How to create a heatmap with one column from RNA seq Differential gene expression data

Tags: r, bioinformatics

Apologies if this question is a repeat, but I couldn't find the answer I'm looking for on here or youtube. Perhaps someone could point me in the right direction?

I have the DGE RNA-seq data for a gene knock down experiment versus a control (with 3 repeats and 3 control repeats). I have 718 genes and have the log2 fold change (LFC) for all of the genes.

In my .txt file that I read into R: I have gene names in the row, and LFC values in a single column. Can I plot a heatmap from this data? I want to be able to visualise which genes are up-regulated or down-regulated. All the other heatmap tutorials I have seen have plotted data for 2 or more columns and I keep getting errors in R.

I am unsure how to proceed now I have read this file in.

Best wishes!

Comment: You can plot it. Can you paste first few lines of your data?

Comment: which error are you getting? To check if the issue is in the code or in the data, you can duplicate your column and plot the heatmap with 2 columns.

Comment: use this tutorial for making heatmap in R for differentially expressed genes. https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/heatmaps_in_r.html